# How to handle button click events in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, meteor-blaze

I have a meteor template:

```
<template name="createDefaultTemplate">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"> Select Role of router</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="routerType">
            <a href="{{pathFor route="edgeRouterAvailablePGTemplate"}}" id= "edge" class="btn btn-default">Edge Router</a>
            <a href="{{pathFor route="aggrRouterAvailablePGTemplate"}}" id= "agg" class="btn btn-default">Aggr. Router</a>
            <a href="{{pathFor route="coreRouterAvailablePGTemplate"}}" id= "core" class="btn btn-default">Core Router</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to pull the value of the button clicked so that I can trigger a  new route. Unfortunately, I'm unable to get it right. I've tried the below, but it does fetch the value from the button.

```
Template.createDefaultTemplate.events({
    'click #agg ': function(event){
        console.log(event);
        var selectValue = $(event.target).val();
        console.log(selectValue + "is selected  - message logged in events");
        Session.set("selectedSchema",selectValue);
        console.log(Session.get("selectedSchema")+ " is session variable set - message logged in events");
    }
});
```

I've also tried something like :

```
 'click' : function(event)
'click a .btn .btn-default' : function(event)
```

But none of them seem to have any effect. I'm able to get a reading of  console.log(event) but I'm unable to extract the value after clicking.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question very well. You need to get a value attach to each of the buttons. You can achieve that by using the data attribute of html element

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="routerType">
        <a href="{{pathFor route="edgeRouterAvailablePGTemplate"}}" id= "edge" data-value="6" class="btn btn-default">Edge Router</a>
        <a href="{{pathFor route="aggrRouterAvailablePGTemplate"}}" id= "agg" data-value="65" class="btn btn-default">Aggr. Router</a>
        <a href="{{pathFor route="coreRouterAvailablePGTemplate"}}" id= "core" class="btn btn-default">Core Router</a>
    </div>
```

To get back the value on a template button click event you can simply do this.

```
    var selectValue = $(event.target).data('value')
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand what are you trying to achieve but as your code appears I believe you are trying to route to different template on button click. If thats what you want then why don't you just keep the routing address in the 'href' property of 'a' tag

```
<a href="/edge" id= "edge" class="btn btn-default">Edge Router</a>
<a href="/aggr" id= "agg" class="btn btn-default">Aggr. Router</a>
<a href="/core" id= "core" class="btn btn-default">Core Router</a>
```

I believe you have already made routes for the buttons clicked so make little modifications of your routers according to hrefs.

I think it should work

If you still want to access the value of href on button click you may do something like this:

```
"click .btn":function(e,t){
  console.log($(e.target).attr("href"))
}
```

Thanks